# how to get a guava ListenableFuture from a callback?

Tags: java, guava, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to use the apache async http client to make asynchronous http calls, in order to run more than one call per thread.

The code is listed here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/quickstart.html

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();

// Start the client
httpclient.start();

// One most likely would want to use a callback for operation result
final CountDownLatch latch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
final HttpGet request2 = new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/");
httpclient.execute(request2, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

    public void completed(final HttpResponse response2) {
        latch1.countDown();
        System.out.println(request2.getRequestLine() + "->" + response2.getStatusLine());
    }

    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
        latch1.countDown();
        System.out.println(request2.getRequestLine() + "->" + ex);
    }

    public void cancelled() {
        latch1.countDown();
        System.out.println(request2.getRequestLine() + " cancelled");
    }

});
latch1.await();
```

In the last time i programmed in nodejs and was very happy with the promise approach. The closest item i found was ListenableFuture from GUAVA. (I can't use Java 8). The question is how to convert the callback approach to ListenableFuture.

In nodejs this would be easy because in the callback i could just call the resolve function. I am not aware how to do this in Java and i did not find in google how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand. You are using the callbacks, if you do not want to handle the future itself, and if you use the future, you do not need a Callback. The way the Guava callbacks work, is that they are statically registered onto a future, so you won't get the future itself, if the Http lib you are using hides it from you. Why do you need the future in the first place? (sorry, why questions are annoying, but it is unclear what you want to achieve)

Comment: My use case is that i want to use existing code which was written in a callback style. I hate callbacks and want to use listenablefutures instead. The question is how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As the API states, a Future is returned by the `execute` method. Since it is linked to a callback it should be a ListenableFuture so

```
ListenableFuture<HttpResponse> future = (ListenableFuture<HttpResponse>) httpclient.execute(...);
```

should do the trick (Inside the callback, you cannot do that). Technically you do not even need to cast the Future, since a normal Future should be sufficient to your use case, since you don't want more Callbacks, if I got you.

If you want to get rid of the callbacks completely (what would be the less messy solution) you need to use another implementation of the HttpClient, but it would require to rewrite code.

Inside the callback however you cannot obtain the future, and you don't need it anyways, since the result of the future is the argument of the callback.

Comment: I want to get ListenableFuture as i can make more complex transformations with it, Also in order to get an answer i will have to block the thread. future.get is blocking. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained Besides this you cannot cast a future to a listenablefuture. There are functions for it.

Comment: So is casting the result of the execute method sufficient or do you need something different?

Comment: casting is not possible. The only way to get a listenablefuture from a future is to have a dedicated thread blocking on the get call which is not nice.

Answer (score 0):

The following post was very helpful: [Turning a listener into a future in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649918/turning-a-listener-into-a-future-in-java)
What i would like to do is:

```
// One most likely would want to use a callback for operation result
final SettableFuture<String> future = SettableFuture.create();
final HttpGet request2 = new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/");
httpclient.execute(request2, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

    public void completed(final HttpResponse response2) {

        future.set(request2.getRequestLine() + "->" + response2.getStatusLine());
    }

    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
        future.set(request2.getRequestLine() + "->" + ex);
    }

    public void cancelled() {

        future.set(request2.getRequestLine() + " cancelled");
    }

});
```